# If $F$ has characteristic $P>0$ prove that $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&\alpha\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $A^p=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $F$ has characteristic $P>0$ prove that $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&\alpha\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ satisfies $A^p=I$.

I am trying to solve this problem but I could not proceed. This is from Herstein algebra book. Please give a hint.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify $F$ and $P$?

Answer (score 3):

You can check that
$$
A^2=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&2\alpha\\ 0&1
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
By induction
$$
A^p=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&p\alpha\\ 0&1
\end{matrix}\right),
$$
but $p\alpha=0$ for $F$ has characteristic $p$, so $A^p=I$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the $n^\text{th}$ power of your matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3\alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$...$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & n\alpha \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$